# Dynamic setting of Style property based on model value

Tags: mvvm, silverlight

Class `Question` represents a question and it's answer. My application renders an ObservableCollection of `Question` objects. Each `Question` is rendered as a StackPanel that contains a TextBlock and a TextBox. The questions are rendered using an ItemsControl and I set the Style of the Questions's StackPanel using a StaticResource key `IncorrectQuestion` (defined in UserControl.Resources).

In UserControl.Resources section I defined a key `CorrectQuestion` which I need to apply to the Question's StackPanel when the user correctly answers. How to dynamically change the Style of the StackPanel within the constraints of a ViewModel class (I don't want to put style selection code in the View)? `Question` class has an `IsCorrect` property which is set when the correction is answered. I'd like to reflect the `IsCorrect` value as a Style selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a value converter is a solution.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BoolToStyleConverter x:Key="Correctness">
            <local:BoolToStyleConverter.FalseValue>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon" />
                </Style>
            </local:BoolToStyleConverter.FalseValue>
            <local:BoolToStyleConverter.TrueValue>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                </Style>
            </local:BoolToStyleConverter.TrueValue>
        </local:BoolToStyleConverter>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question}" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="Answer" Text="{Binding Answer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       Style="{Binding IsCorrect, Converter={StaticResource Correctness}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>        
</Grid>
```

You can find the basis for the `BoolToStyleConverter` is based on this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200627025931/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx).
Created as:-

```
public class BoolToStyleConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Style> { }
```

Comment: I tried using a Value Converter but I coulnd't get it to work. I think I was just doing something wrong. I will revisit that option. Cheers!